# access subfolders of subdomain htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created a subdomain to point to a folder on my root directory like this;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

I can now access files of the `/blog` folder like this `http://blog.example.co.uk/index.php`

The `/blog` folder contains a `/php` folder containing scripts.
I'm unable to access the `/php` folder like this `http://blog.example.co.uk/php/test.php`

This doesn't work. For me to access them I have to do this `http://www.example.co.uk/blog/php/test.php`

Below is my current `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
### Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
### Prevent rules on script folder in root /php & /blog/php because I remove .php extension from all files
RewriteRule ^(php|blog/php)($|/) - [L]
### To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
### To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
### My subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

Now I need to create a rule to point `http://blog.example.co.uk/php` to `/blog/php`

Thanks guys

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work" ? Where are you redirected if you go to http://www.example.co.uk/blog/php/test.php ?

Comment: File not found is what I get